# Grails change default show view after update() gets called in controller

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I have a controller in my grails 3.2.9 project that was created using the generate-controller command. I would like to change the default view that gets rendered after the update() method in the controller is called. It defaults to rendering the show.gsp, but I would like it to render a custom gsp. Is it possible to change this behavior? I've tried changing the last line of the update() method to:

`'*'{ respond BOSI, [status: OK, view: 'myView'] }`

but the show.gsp continues to get rendered. I'm fairly new to the grails framework, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you shown is a part of the following construct:

```
request.withFormat{
  form multipartForm{
    flash.message = '' // some message
    redirect some
  }
  '*'{ respond some, [ status:OK ] }
}
```

and is used to respond to REST-calls and has nothing to do with GSPs. If you want to adjust the GSP rendering, you have to modify the other lines:

```
request.withFormat{
  form multipartForm{
    flash.message = '' // some message
    redirect action:'myView', id:some.id
    // or
    render view:'myView', model:[ some:some ]
  }
  '*'{ respond some, [ status:OK ] }
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with the redirect since that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you